# if $f(g(x))=x^3$ and $g(f(x))=x^4$ find $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

Tags: functions

I am taking algebra two and questions like this popped into my head so I would like to learn how to solve them, I am currently working on composing functions.

Comment: I would start by thinking there might be a solution of the form $f(x) = x^a$ and $g(x) = x^b$ and trying to find $a$ and $b$. (I haven't tried to see if this works. You can.)

Comment: @EthanBolker No, this doesn't work because $f\circ g=g \circ f$ in this case.

Comment: This is a very interesting question. I proved that no such functions exist [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3064078/prove-that-nexists-functions-f-g-bbbr-to-bbbr-such-that-fgx-x2/3064462#3064462)

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy True. That is where I'd have begun, and would quickly have found that it doesn't work. Nothing will, as per other comments.

Comment: you can take a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3065170/are-there-two-functions-f-g-such-that-fgx-x3-and-gfx-x5?noredirect=1&lq=1 is asked by @MaximilianJanisch

Answer (score 3):

We have $$ f(x^4) = f(g(f(x)) = (f(x))^3 $$
Let $F(y) := \log f(e^y)$. We have
$$ F(4y) = \log f(e^{4y}) = \log \big((f(e^y))^3\big) = 3\log f(e^y) = 3F(y) $$
You can easily construct such functions. You can take any function $F : (-4,-1]\cup[1,4) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and then define $F(4^k y) = 3^k F(y)$ for $k\in\mathbb Z$, which will define $F: (-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R$, and finally put $F(0)=0$.

You can take then $$ f(x) = \exp F(\log x)$$
which will define $f: (0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb (0,\infty)$.
If this function turns out to be invertible (which happens if $F:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is invertible), then you can define $g(x) = f^{-1}(x^3)$

Example:
$$ F(y) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} y^{\log_4 3} & \text{for }y>0 \\ 0 & \text{for }y=0 \\ -(-y)^{\log_4 3} &\text{for }y<0 \end{array}\right.$$ $$ f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} \exp\big((\log x)^{\log_4 3}\big) & \text{for }x>1 \\ 1 & \text{for }x=1 \\ \exp\big(-(-\log x)^{\log_4 3}\big) &\text{for }0<x<1 \end{array}\right.$$ $$ g(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} \exp\big((3\log x)^{\log_3 4}\big) & \text{for }x>1 \\ 1 & \text{for }x=1 \\ \exp\big(-(-3\log x)^{\log_3 4}\big) &\text{for }0<x<1 \end{array}\right.$$

Comment: +1 This is a nice construction; it is impossible to extend this to $\Bbb R$ though