# Do there exist functions $f:\Bbb {R} \to \Bbb {R} $ and $g:\Bbb {R} \to \Bbb {R} $ such that $f(g(x)) =x^2$ and $g(f(x)) =x^4$?

Tags: functions, set-theory

Do there exist functions $f:\Bbb {R} \to \Bbb {R} $ and $g:\Bbb {R} \to \Bbb {R} $ such that $f(g(x)) =x^2$ and $g(f(x)) =x^4$?
**Try**
Let $f(x) =x^m$ and $g(x) =x^n$ where $m\neq n$. Then $f(g(x)) =x^{mn} $ and $g(f(x)) =x^{mn} $. This two implies that $mn=2$ and $mn=4$ simultaneously. Which is impossible.
Am I correct?  I want to know if there is any alternative way to argue this question?

Comment: Your reasoning is incorrect since you just explained why there are not functions *of the form $x^n$ and $x^m$* that don't meet the conclusions. You did not treat the general case.

Comment: Your reasoning is valid for polynomial equation,though

Comment: may help : 1)(exact qsn.) https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1182470p5730121 2) (not same but close ) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3064078/how-to-prove-that-there-exist-no-functions-f-g-bbbr-to-bbbr-such-that-f

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define $$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0& \text{if }x=0\\
e^{2\sqrt{-\log(|x|)}}& \text{if } 0 < |x| < 1\\
e^{2\sqrt{\log(|x|)}}& \text{if } |x| \geq 1
\end{cases} \quad \quad \text{and} \quad \quad g(x)=
\begin{cases}
0& \text{if }x=0\\
e^{-\log^2(|x|)}& \text{if } 0 < |x| < 1\\
e^{\log^2(|x|)}& \text{if } |x| \geq 1
\end{cases}$$

Then $f$ and $g$ meet the required conclusions : indeed,

$\bullet\ $ If $x=0$, one has $f(g(x))=f(0)=0=0^2$ and $g(f(x))=g(0)=0=0^4$.

$\bullet\ $ If $0 < |x| < 1$, one has
$$f(g(x)) = f(e^{-\log^2(|x|)}) = e^{2\sqrt{\log^2(|x|)}} = x^2$$
$$g(f(x))=g(e^{2\sqrt{-\log(|x|)}}) = e^{-\left(2\sqrt{-\log(|x|)}\right)^2} = x^4 $$

$\bullet\ $ If $|x| > 1$, then
$$f(g(x))=f(e^{\log^2(|x|)}) = e^{2\sqrt{\log^2(|x|)}} = x^2$$

$$g(f(x))=g(e^{2 \sqrt{\log(|x|)}}) = e^{(2 \sqrt{\log(|x|)})^2} = x^4$$

---

**Explanation on how to find such functions :**

By composing the equalities $f(g(x))=x^2$ and $g(f(x))=x^4$ by $g$ and $f$ respectively, you get that $f$ and $g$ must satisfy $f(x)^2=f(x^4)$ and $g(x)^4=g(x^2)$. In other words, $f_{|[0, +\infty)}$ must be a conjugacy between $x \mapsto x^4$ and $x \mapsto x^2$ on $[0,+\infty)$, and  $g_{|[0, +\infty)}$ must be a conjugacy between $x \mapsto x^2$ and $x \mapsto x^4$ on $[0,+\infty)$.

So I tried to construct such conjugacies, which is not so difficult : indeed, $x \mapsto x^2$ is conjugate to $x \mapsto 2x$ (thanks to the $\log$), which is conjugate to $x \mapsto 4x$ (quite easily), which is conjugate to $x \mapsto x^4$ (again thanks to the $\log$). Composing all these conjugacies leads to the given expressions for $f$ and $g$.

Comment: But the solution creates another big question. How do you find or construct such functions which I think not obvious at all!

Comment: @Math-Learner I edited my answer to explain how I found them.

Comment: Can you find continuous $f, g$?

Comment: I'm unable to understand what is conjugacy here?

Comment: @Math-Learner A conjugacy between two maps $g$ and $h$ is a bijective map $f$ such that $g  =f \circ h \circ f^{-1}$.